# Using for-loop writing a function with inputing a list

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Question:

"write a program with a car's miles/gallon and gas dollars/gallon (both floats) as input, and output the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles."

I understand there is a way to just print them out individually, but i believe there should be a for loop to do this, so even if you enter more driven_miles, it will iterate from the for loop,

could anyone help me? thank you!

Below is my code that i am having issues with:

```
def driving_cost(a, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    cost = a / miles_per_gallon * dollars_per_gallon
    return cost
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driven_miles = [10, 50, 400]
    miles_per_gallon = input()
    dollars_per_gallon = input()
    for i in range(len(driven_miles)):
        a = driven_miles[i]
        print(driving_cost(a, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon))
```

Comment: Please be more clear as to what the problem is. Also, when I run the code, I get an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'`. Question code should be free of errors that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: ok, thank you for your suggestion, i have clarified my prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def driving_cost(a, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    cost = (a / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon
    return cost
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driven_miles = [10, 50, 400]
    miles_per_gallon = float(input())
    dollars_per_gallon = float(input())
    for i in range(len(driven_miles)):
        cost = driving_cost(driven_miles[i], miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon)
        print('{:.2f}'.format(cost))
```

I have worked on the solution guys.
1st I set the function by calculating the cost using the 3 parameters
2nd I did for loop in the outcome with length of driven_miles so it will iterate 1 by 1, then print out the answer.
Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now, cost is a single value. You could initialize cost as an empty list, and append each individual cost to it, returning it at the end

```
def driving_cost(driven_miles, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    cost = []
    for miles in driven_miles:
        cost.append((miles / miles_per_gallon) * dollars_per_gallon)

    return cost
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very nice helper.
Its signature is

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
```

You want to embellish its signature so a 3rd arg is tacked on:

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, driven_miles):
```

That, or define the list down within the helper.

---

Iterating over indexes is certainly possible,
as your `for i in range(len(driven_miles)):` loop currently does.
It would require a de-reference, such as `driven_miles[i]`.

But it is more natural to ignore indexes and just iterate through the elements:

```
for dm in driven_miles:
```

---

Currently you loop over three values to compute three costs,
and you **overwrite** `cost` each time.
So the 3rd cost value winds up being returned.

Consider moving the `print` down within that loop.
Or restructure the code so the helper returns a single cost
and the looping / print responsibilities are up in the main function.